# How to combine 2 hashmaps into 1

Tags: java

Is there a way to combine two hashmaps into a third third hashmap?

Example:

```
Hashmap 1 has  {key1, value1}, {key2, value2}, {key3, value3)
Hashmap 2 has  {key1, value1}, {key2, value2}
Hashmap 3 has  {key1, value1}, {key2, value2}, {key3, value3), {key1, value1}, {key2, value2}
```

Below is an example code:

```
Map<String, Object> body1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> body2 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();

table.getTableRows().forEach(row -> {
    String value = row.getCell(VALUE);
    String field = row.getCell(FIELD);

    if (body1.containsKey(field)) {
        body2.put(field, value);
    } else {
        body1.put(field, value);
    }
});

//Append both hashmaps into one - body
```

Comment: is key1 in hashmap1 equivalent to key1 in hasmap2? HashMap keys must be unique if that's the case.

Comment: Can [use the merge method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashmap-mergekey-value-bifunction-method-in-java-with-examples/) for this I believe.

Comment: You can have only one value with the same key i.e. you can not have `{key1, value1}` twice or more. Whenever you will add an entry as `{key1, value1}`, it will replace the old entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only one value with the same key i.e. you can not have `{key1, value1}` twice or more. Whenever you will add an entry with `key1`, it will replace the old value of `key1`.

If you want to keep both the maps in one collection, you need to use a different collection e.g. `List`. Given below is a demo using `List`:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, Object> body1=Map.of("key1","value1","key2","value2","key3","value3");
        Map<String, Object> body2=Map.of("key1","value1","key2","value2");
        List<Map<String, Object>> body=List.of(body1,body2);
        for(Map<String, Object> map:body) {
            System.out.println(map);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}
{key2=value2, key1=value1}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the keys in the maps are unique you can use `Map.putAll(Map map):`

```
body.putAll(body1);
body.putAll(body2);
```

if the keys are not unique you could do something like:

```
    body.putAll(body1);
    for (Map.Entry entry : (Set<Map.Entry>)body2.entrySet()) {
        if (body.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
              //either replace or keep old value
              //body.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
        } else {
              body.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
       }
    }
```