# How to convert a list of two hashmaps back into a Map?

Tags: java

I just need a little help completing the below. Basically I have two hash map lists (body1 and body 2) and I need to merge them into one (body). The issue I have is how to do this and convert body into a Map because I need to pass in body as a post request and that takes in a Map. It has to be a map because that method uses a built in unirest function:

```
((HttpRequestWithBody) httpRequest).fields(...);
```

And fields has to be a Map.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, Object> body1=Map.of("key1","value1","key2","value2","key3","value3");
        Map<String, Object> body2=Map.of("key1","value1","key2","value2");
        List<Map<String, Object>> body=List.of(body1,body2);
        for(Map<String, Object> map:body) {
            //not sure what goes here
        }
    }

    final String url = String.format("%s/.../service/", System.getenv(ENDPOINT), service);
    new DBRequest(dataStore, url, HttpMethod.POST).postRequest(body);
}
```

```
public HttpResponse postRequest(Map body) {
    ((HttpRequestWithBody) httpRequest).fields(body);
    return sendRequest();
}
```

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299728/how-can-i-combine-two-hashmap-objects-containing-the-same-types

Comment: you have to be more specific about the merge. what about keys that are present in both maps like key1 and key2? which value do you want in the merged map or are they always the same?

Comment: you marked this op as a solution to your former question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762969/how-to-combine-2-hashmaps-into-1 and now it turns out it is not the solution?

Comment: If you want a map with duplicate keys, then you would have to use a different Map implementation. You may try checking out this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-map-duplicate-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **merge()** function into the java.util.Map interface. This way you can also introduce the logic to apply if two elements on your maps have the same key.

Here is a junit example I made where logic applied in the case of key conflict is to concatenate element string values with pattern **"value1-value2"** if values are differents:

```
@Test
public void mapMergeTest(){
    Map<String, Object> body1=Map.of("key1","value1","key2","value2","key3","value3");
    System.out.println("Merged body1: \n"+body1);
    Map<String, Object> body2=Map.of("key1","value1","key2","value2");
    System.out.println("Merged body2: \n"+body2);

    Map<String, Object> mergedBody = new HashMap<>(body1);
    body2.forEach(
                (key, value) -> {
                    mergedBody.merge(key, value, (v1, v2) -> {
                        if(v1.equals(v2))
                            return v1.toString();
                        return v1.toString() + "-" + v2.toString();
                    });
                });
    System.out.println("Merged body: \n"+mergedBody);
}
```

The output is:

```
Body1: 
{key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}
Body2: 
{key1=value5, key2=value2}
Merged body: 
{key1=value1-value5, key2=value2, key3=value3}
```

So just change the merge key conflict logic according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for that gcallea, can you show me how to pass it through the post request line please? Is it still body I pass through into that line?

Comment: You're welcome. You should pass the **mergedBody** variable on your postRequest method ( taking care of the logic you would apply generating that merged map as I explained into my answer )

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to introduce a list? Would something like this work for you?

```
body1.putAll(body2);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that overwrite same key values?